# How can I get constraints working in grails if I'm using JPA annotated classes from a jar file?

Tags: jpa, grails, grails-domain-class

Bottomline, 
I'm using Grails 1.3.7 and using JPA annotated classes from a JAR file, 
But the constraints are not working, meaning they are ignored even if I explicitly code them, like usual in the domain classes,

Is there a way I can get the constraints working?

Comment: Are the JPA classes .java or .groovy classes?

Comment: Are you trying to add the constraints using JPA annotations or the a Grails `constraints` closure?

Answer (score 0):

@Don

1.- JPA classes are .java inside a jar file, I've created Grails Domain classes using this .java classes by just using the grails create-domain-class and using the corresponding package to the .java, so the outcome result in the grail project is

Domain
 \
com.myapp.Clazz.groovy 
  \

package com.myapp.Clazz
class Clazz {

}

Later, I tried to add a Constraint.groovy file to the src/java folder with my constraints, as specified in the following article: [Reuse your hibernate/jpa](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/26/reuse-your-hibernatejpa-domain-model-with-grails/)

But when I tried to run the app the compiler gets into an infinte cycle and never finish to compile the project..

Comment: @jjczopek
I did tried the @Validateable annotation, but it ignores it, I believe it's because the JPA classes are in the jar file and the constraints are static

Comment: did you register relevant packages with Config.groovy to tell grails where to look for validateable classes?

Comment: @jjczopek Thanks for replying, yes here is how it looks my Config.groovy and my Domain Class based on my JPA annotated java class

package com.myapp

import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.Validateable

@Validateable
class Clazz {
 static constraints = {
  prop1(blank:false) 
 }
}

**Config.groovy

grails.validateable.packages = ['com.myapp']
grails.validateable.classes = [com.myapp.Clazz]

But still, constraints are just ignored

Answer (score -1):

Grails documentation [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/7.%20Validation.html#7.5%20Validation%20Non%20Domain%20and%20Command%20Object%20Classes) says, that if you annotate your class with `@Validateable` and provide a static constraints block inside class and register its package in Config.groovy, you will be able to validate this class as usual.